# How to find email with more than 2 dots using REGEXP MySQL function?

Tags: mysql, regex, email

I have a big user database with a lot of spammy email account, like `j.o.hnha.r.rold.t.ho.mp.so.n.j.u.n.io.r@gmail.com` or `o.f.vst.p.rqlsy.j@gmail.com` and I want to remove them with one queries (instead of doing a php script that parses all the database).

I see MySQL have a REGEXP function, but it's hard to use it with "dot". I tried lots of things like :

- `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email REGEXP '([[...]]){2,}'`
- `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email REGEXP '(\\.){2,}'`
- `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email REGEXP '(.*)[[...]]{2}(.*)'`

Each one fails.

Any ideas ?

Comment: 2 dots? What about joe.bloggs@example.co.uk for instance? ( This argument could go on for ever ). Why do you care if they're spammy?

Comment: `f.o.o.b.a.r@gmail.com` goes to same account as `foobar@gmail.com`.

Comment: @Ben I just want to clean my database.

Comment: @j0k how do you know they are spammy? I frequently add extra dots to my gmail address when I want to be able to pre-filter the messages I get to that address. Gmail strips all dots from emails when it delivers them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

how about this?

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email REGEXP '[.].*[.].*@';
```

this searches for two (or more) dots before @ (which would still allow multi-dot domain names like .co.uk etc).

However, you should consider the possibility that some users may really have multiple dots in their username as well, and that will still be legit.

Comment: Thanks, I won't perform a massive `delete from`.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, this is usually only a spam issue when a gmail.com account is used.  Most legitimate usernames with multiple dots will be something like jason.b.williams@gmail.com - so spammers who use 3 or more dots in their username - I will be pruning from my database, and I will be implementing code to the registration process to disallow the use of more than 2 dots in the username when a gmail address is used.

```
SELECT user_email FROM users WHERE email REGEXP '[.].*[.].*[.].*@';
```

Comment: Why? Please don't. The number of dots in a gmail address means nothing. I hate it when sites won't let me add a '+' sign to my gmail address and I'd hate it even more if there was an arbitrary rule preventing me from being able to add extra dots to my address instead.