# Looking for a PHP regex or function to filter variations using . of an email for security

Tags: php, javascript, html, regex, joomla

I am getting spam due to gmail allowing the use of **.** in their emails, so someone like this spammer.

```
q.i.n.ghu.im.i.n.g.o.u.r@gmail.com
```

can get through by removing and/or adding another period in his naming structure. 
This happens to be on a Joomla install, so I am specifically looking to create a component so I can add to multiple sites, or if there is a simple regex to add inline existing code. Also, is there anything being done about this, as this seems to be along the lines of and be newly termed a **loosely typed email address**.. that is crazy to me.

Comment: [I've got same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762928/how-to-find-email-with-more-than-2-dots-using-regexp-mysql-function), I directly removed user in database using SQL, but it can be a starting point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your goal is to match this address against the others that are equivalent to it (because you've already got them blacklisted) then I'd simply normalize the address to it's most basic state before storing it. Lower case it, split it at the @, and if the right side is "gmail.com" then remove all dots from the left side and put the halves back together.

1. start with JOE.SCHMOE@GMAIL.COM
2. lowercase to joe.schmoe@gmail.com
3. split to joe.schmoe and gmail.com
4. since right side is gmail.com, remove dots from left
5. reassemble to joeschmoe@gmail.com

Now you've got the base address that you can block/ban/whatever.

Comment: That sounds fairly good, the only issue is going to lowercase and/or to uppercase is a frequent debate, though it looks as though most accounts are not case sensitive anymore as far as I can tell. Gmail is so good, I wish I knew why they allow this so I don't have to make code specific to them. Safari and IE are already causing me to write so much extra code already.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something *simple* like: `/^(?:[^@]+\.){5,}[^@]+@(?:[^@]+\.)+[^@]+/`

This is just quick toss up not meant for validation, but rather, a pointer to tell you if their email is scetchy. The key here is the `{5,}` quantifier that says if the email has 5 or more dots (like `a.b.c.d.e.f`) it will match. In other words be flagged as scetchy.

I hope this helps!

Explanation: http://regex101.com/r/lB5vG3

Comment: @Lundrian I will look at this solution as well, possibly reducing the combinations at least of what this person/bot can enter for one account. I have never looked or thought about how often people legitimately use periods in their email, so could possibly prevent valid users. Might have to create a user notified rule, so they are aware of if denied access.

Comment: I have to recommend against the outright denial of a perfectly valid email address like this. I've had numerous merchant websites refuse my TMDA-encoded address for this same reason -- it's quite annoying, often leads to lots of time-wasting debugging, and invariably results in their loss of my business.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Thank you, that answers my question on the potential drawbacks to doing this.